# Select rows from table where each row refers to a different schema

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, select

I have customer table in public schema. And I have a schema named after each customer. Each customer schema contains different tables like `portals`, `plugin`, ... When I want to select portals used by customer 'a', I can do `select * from a.portal`.

I want to select *all* the customers having a particular 'portal name'. But portal table is inside customer schema. So how should I query in this situation?

I have found solution using a PHP script but is there anything that we can do on the DB level?

Comment: In order to get a meaningful answer (longer than 'Look into dynamic SQL'), please give an example of how `portal` tables differ among customers.

Comment: actually description of each portal inside every customer schema (for example a.portal or b.portal,where a and b are customers )is same.they don't differ in structure.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**inheritance**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html) for this. You would have a "master" schema with template tables and only the basic set of columns that all inheriting tables share:

```
CREATE TABLE master.portal(portal_name text);
```

All other tables in various schemata inherit from it, while possibly adding more local columns:

```
CREATE TABLE a.portal(portal_id serial PRIMARY KEY, col2 text)
INHERITS (master.portal);

CREATE TABLE b.portal(portal_id serial PRIMARY KEY, col2 text, col3 text)
INHERITS (master.portal);
```

A `SELECT` query targeted on the master table would then search *all* child tables as well:

```
SELECT portal_name, tableoid::regclass::text AS source
FROM   master.portal
WHERE  portal_name ILIKE '%test%';
```

More details in this closely related answer on SO:

- [Retrieve all records from multiple schemas in a PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576324/939860)